# Withdrew when Jimmy met up with Heath

Tags: cryptic-clues

Withdrew when Jimmy met up with Heath.  The answer is retracted but I can't work out why.  I guess a tract is a heath but I still haven't been able to put the whole word together.

<sup>*Source: New Zealand [Herald on Sunday, Aug 11 2019](https://www.pressreader.com/new-zealand/herald-on-sunday/20190811/page/72)*</sup>

Answer (score 9):

This also leads to the answer:

> [Jimmy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Carter) RETRAC< + TED [Heath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Heath) → RETRACTED  (up as a reversal if a down clue)

Comment: I'm nailing my flag to this mast - a perfect (and comfortable) solution +1

Answer (score 7):

I think it’s

> {Definition:} Withdrew when Jimmy {Potentially [Jimmy Reed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Reed) clueing REED} met up with Heath {a heath is a TRACT of land as you’ve mentioned}.

So you get

> TRACT in RE_____ED yielding RETRACTED, with definition WITHDREW.

Comment: I'm sure this answer is correct, but... eew. What kind of way to indicate an insertion is that??

Comment: Yeah, “met up with” is a really bad one..... I mean, I suppose it could also be an anagram indicator, but it’s still not the best haha